# Gdebi keeps crashing when "Install" is clicked

Tags: software-installation, package-management, dpkg

I'm having an issue with gdebi, where it launches and loads the package I'm trying to install just fine, but whenever I click on "Install" it crashes and quits.  I don't mind having to use `dpkg -i` while I'm sorting this out, the gui method is just easier when I don't really want to bother with the terminal approach.

I've already tried `apt remove`, `apt autoremove` and `apt purge` but each time I reinstall it, the same crash keeps occurring.

I'd be fine if you want to just suggest using another extremely lightweight gui pm installer, but I really don't want to launch the heavyweights like gnome-software, or appgrid.

If you'd like more info, please tell me what to copy/paste so you can see the error logs.

Anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does gdebi crash when you install the package via terminal?

Answer (score 5):

This started happening to me in November also.

But GDebi is not actually crashing. If you run it in a terminal:

```
gdebi /path/to/.deb
```

It terminates with "must be root to install software packages"

Try:

```
sudo gdebi /path/to/.deb
```

I am accustomed to right-click `.deb` "Install with `GDebi`", but this currently does not work.

Comment: Running GDebi GUI as superuser helps. This can be done purely in GUI, open the `.deb` location in file manager, right click on the directory, "open as superuser" and  then open the package in the newly opened window

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion here to modify the .desktop file has the right concept, but if you can't get gksudo on your modern Linux installation then try the following:

Edit your gdebi.desktop file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gdebi.desktop
```

(Obviously, if you don't have "gedit", replace that with "nano" or whatever your preferred editor is.)

Now change the line:

```
Terminal=false
```

to:

```
Terminal=true
```

A minor quirk about this approach is you'll see a terminal window quickly flash and close but this should allow the application to prompt you for your password when you click "Install" which will grant the necessary permissions to actually begin installation.

Comment: nice trick, That worked for me on kali2020.2

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/applications/gdebi.desktop
```

Find the line:

```
Exec=gdebi-gtk %f
```

Make it read:

```
Exec=gksudo gdebi-gtk %f
```

SAVE the file.

That fixes it.

Comment: Do you also have an explanation?

Comment: instead of `gksudo`, maybe `pkexec` is the more up-to-date approach (see, for example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/252962/is-there-a-desktop-neutral-gksudo).

Answer (score 0):

@Causeless Effect: Setting Terminal=true in the gdebi.desktop file was the solution for me too.

> A minor quirk about this approach is you'll see a terminal window quickly flash and close but this should allow the application to prompt you for your password when you click "Install" which will grant the necessary permissions to actually begin installation.

On my system the 'minor quirk' is a bit different.
When selecting a file in my file manager, right-click and select the option 'open with gdebi package installer', first a terminal window is opened, and in front of that the GUI of gdebi. Using the GUI works perfectly fine, and closing the GUI also closes the terminal window behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not crashing as people said. It just can't install apps because you are not running with `sudo`.

So you can run:

```bash
sudo gdebi-gtk
```

Then, `Gdebi` with GUI will appear and you will be able to install `.deb` packages.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Considering there are already multiple answers with essentially the same info, to prevent this from being flagged as "low quality answer" I'd suggest you edit your answer to clarify how exactly this differs from the already-provided answers. I'd also recommend you read through the Help, sections about questions and answers to learn how things work. SE communities aren't discussion forums.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem: make sure that the .deb package is not "read only" in its properties.

Worked for me.

Comment: Hi Daga, could you go into more detail the specific steps of making sure that package is not read-only?